# Passing a list of values to remap in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering if there was a way to pass a list of values/corresponding values that I am remapping in my dataframe. I am using a truncated version of my dataset and would rather not have to update the code one by one, there are about 30 different unique QFundMaster variables in my data.

```
 QFundMaster    NPS
0   3   1
1   5   2
2   10  3
3   23  9
4   26  1
```

The code I am using to remap the data is as follows:

```
df['Fund'] = df['QFundMaster'] \
.map({3: 'Fund1'\
  ,5: 'Fund2'\
  ,10: 'Fund3'\
  ,23: 'Fund4'\
  ,26: 'Fund5'})
```

The code works perfectly fine, but was after a way to pass a list of values/new values so I don't have to edit the code one by one and to make it more efficient. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
print(df.Fund)
0    Fund1
1    Fund2
2    Fund3
3    Fund4
4    Fund5
Name: Fund, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the list of `old_values` and `new_values`, you could do:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[3, 1],
        [5, 2],
        [10, 3],
        [23, 9],
        [26, 1]]

df =pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['QFundMaster', 'NPS'])

old_values = [3, 5, 10, 23, 26]
new_values = ['Fund1', 'Fund2', 'Fund3', 'Fund4', 'Fund5']

df['Fund'] = df['QFundMaster'].map(dict(zip(old_values, new_values)))

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   QFundMaster  NPS   Fund
0            3    1  Fund1
1            5    2  Fund2
2           10    3  Fund3
3           23    9  Fund4
4           26    1  Fund5
```